# Getting WSO2 ESB endpoint meta data programmatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to programmatically retrieve the meta data of the end points configured to WSO2 ESB (Eg: ServiceName, WebMethods, Input/Output Parameters with Return types etc). Can someone direct me to some way/docs which could help me fetch this data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not really clear what you want to do. Here some examples how to access properties (Meta-Data?)

inside a proxy/sequence access properties:

```
<property name="some name" expression="get-property('registry','conf:resource/path')"/>
<property name="some name" expression="get-property('registry',gov:resource/path')"/>
<property name="some name" expression="get-property('registry','resourceName')"/>
```

Or inside a Custom Mediator:

```
String property = (String)messageContext.getProperty("nameOfThePropery");
```

Or inside a Custom Mediator (getting the filename from the Transport Layer):

```
org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2messageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) messageContext).getAxis2MessageContext();
// print the filename of the current transport
myLog.info("FileName: " + axis2messageContext.getTransportIn().getName());
```

Hope this helps you a little bit further, otherwise improve you question.

Answer (score 0):

To further improve on Abdul's question, we are developing a web-service gateway between a legacy client on side and on the other side are external web-services. We have created a template/sequences in WSo2 where we trap the legacy client request and redirect it to the correct web-service based on a internal protocol.

The external web services are registered in WSo2 as endpoints. So far we have been configuring these endpoints manually using the admin console. We are looking at automating this step so that our gateway will hit WSo2 and provide the WSDL URL. A class mediator would then invoke the WSo2 / Synapse APIs to save this endpoint in the Synapse configuration. We have not been successful in this.

We have also read the docs which say that changing synapse config thru mediator is not recommended, hence would like to see if there are other options that would do this job for us.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to create those endpoints from the client side itself. This can be done by calling the AdminService APIs exposed by the carbon framework. In carbon, a front end of any carbon component talks to its back end through Admin Services. For example, if we take endpoints related functionalities, when you use the management console to create/delete or to do any functionalities, it would in turn call the respective back end via the "EndPointAdmin" admin service. Therefore I believe, if you want to programmatically create those endpoints, you can call the EndPointAdmin backend admin service (via EndPointAdminStub - it is the client stub corresponding to the aforesaid back end service) directly from your client side and get your requirement fulfilled.

Regards,
Prabath